# Get count of rows on the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Parent component that makes an `API` call and passes the data to its children using a map function as the Parents `API` call returns an array. Now in the child component, each array result from the parent is used to make another `API` call. The second `API` call will populate the rows on the client.  How do I get the count of the children rows that are shown on the clients' screen?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rows-count has a working example, initially, the parent has an array of elements [1,2,3,4] and we are mapping each value in Parent and passing the current array value to the Child component.

In the Child component, we are checking if the passed value satisfies the **value%2 === 0** condition, and based on it we are adding new values to the child's state. if the condition is satisfied we are creating a new array with the value as **setHelper([value, value])** and if not satisfy the condition we are creating an array as  **setHelper([i*4,i*5])**.

In the below example, the **Parent** has an array and mapping over the array to create 'n' number of children components and passing the array value as the prop to each **Child**. In the Child component, using **useEffect** and based on the value of the prop `i` using a state value `helper` and updating it to an array based on the condition.

if current value gives `i%2 === 0` then the array value would be `[i,i]`, else if we are adding `[i*4,i*5]` to the state and if `i === 5` then we won't be displaying anything on the screen as now helper is not an array and is set to 0.

if `helper` is an array, we are mapping the array values inside the Child component to display.

How do I get the final count of the number of new rows in the Child component and read this value in the Parent component?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child'

const Parent = ()=>{
let parentState= [1,2,3,4,5]

  return (
    <>
    <p>Parent Array is {parentState}</p>
    <p>child new array is </p>
    {parentState.map((i,index)=>(
    <Child i={i}/>
    ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.js

```
import React ,{useEffect,useState}from 'react';
const Child = ({i})=>{ 
const [helper, setHelper]=useState(i)

useEffect(()=>{
if(i%2 === 0){
  setHelper([i,i])
}else if(i == 5){
  setHelper(0)
}
else{
  setHelper([i*4,i*5])
}
},[])


if(Array.isArray(helper)){
return (
  <>
  {helper.map((i,index)=>(
    <div className="child-row">
    <p>-----</p>
    <h4>{i}</h4>
    <p>-----</p>
    </div>
  ))}
  </>
)
}
else{
  return <></>
}
}

export default Child
```

Comment: Can you use the `length` property of the array you are mapping?

Comment: the length in the parent will not be appropriate to use as the child will be populating the rows.

Comment: So by populate rows do you mean they are adding more rows, each?

Comment: yes, based on each API call in the child, they will be adding a new row.

Comment: *A* new row to me implies a one-to-one relationship with the mapped data array. Please update your question to include more specific details of your code setup. If you include your code it may be much easier to see how to aggregate a total row count.

Comment: @visizky, can you provide your sample code, so I can be able to help you to fix it?

Comment: @Maf you can access the stack blitz link. instead of the actual API using an array to showcase the issue

Comment: We could go directly to the point instead of analysing a full API in github

Comment: How do I get the final count of the number of new rows in the Child component and read this value in the Parent component? Which problem are you facing with this question?

Comment: get the count of the number of rows, this value has to be accessed in the Parent

Comment: Your link 404s. Please just provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of *your* code, explain your attempt to solve a problem, what specific issue you have, and a detailed expected result. Without these there's not much the community can do.

Comment: @DrewReese the link is updated and have added the code snippet

Comment: From `useEffect` hook code, you always end up with exactly two rows in the child component. Check this out [link](https://rows-count-cjgsmt.stackblitz.io)